# Enable Skype for business channel for a chatbot

Tags: powershell, azure, botframework, chatbot, skype-for-business

I am using one Azure account where I have the AD app linked with Skype for business subscription, and another Azure account where I have hosted the chatbot.

I am running the following powershell commands:

```
Import-PSSession (New-CsOnlineSession -Credential (Get-Credential))
```

and:

```
New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationId 561bae84-ea1c-4f75-a512-b84566779c2w -Name NameOfTheBot -Uri sip:username@yourdomain.com
```

With, of course, giving name and sip id.

I am getting following error in powershell:

```
Cmdlet invocation error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], CmdletInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error processing cmdlet request,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatf
   ormServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminin1.online.lync.com

Could not find the application endpoint
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Rtc.M...cation endpoint:PlatformServiceCmdletException) [Ne
   w-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint], PlatformServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not get application endpoint or the Uri is already present as an User in BVD,Micro
   soft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.PlatformService.NewPlatformServiceAppEndpointConfigCmdlet
    + PSComputerName        : adminin1.online.lync.com
```

Should Skype for business and chatbot be linked with the same account?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with those PowerShell commands? I'm not familiar with PowerShell and I've never seen anyone create/edit a bot with PowerShell, that might be the limitation here.

Comment: I want to enable skype for business channel for the bot, but the problem is, my bot is hosted on different azure account than the account linked with skype for business subscription.

Comment: In [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/Skype-For-Business-Bot-Framework/docs/bot-common-errors), it lists the most common errors encountered during the Skype for Business Bot setup, you can check it.